# KQL Remove from array if array item contains equals condition

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I have a log source which has the following format:

```
//file1.png is the filename, the parenthesis hold the filesize in bytes.
// Each item is separated by a semicolon.
file1.png (445b); file2.pdf (2345b); file3.jpg (343b); file4.docx (3243b);
```

I have this regex to split the items into a list of lists, with 0 being the filename, 1 the extension and 2 the size in bytes. This can be copied as a test:

```
datatable (item:string ) [
'file1.png (445b); file2.pdf (2345b); file3.jpg (343b); file4.docx (3243b);',
'file1.src (3243b); file2.ps2 (24b); file3.jpg (300b); file4.jpg (326b);'
]
| extend list = extract_all(@'([^<>:"\/\\\|\?\*;]+)\.([a-zA-z0-9]+) \((\d+)b\);', item)
```

This outputs as the following:

`[["file1", ".png", "343"], ["file2", ".pdf", "232"],...]`

**I want to remove items from the list if the sublist contains certain filetypes (such as .png). How would I go about doing this? KQL has no iteration features as far as I know.**

I have tried using regex to exclude the queries I do not want to match. It was the following: `(?:^|; =?)([^<>:"\/\\\|\?\*;]+\.(?!jpg\b|png\b)\w+ \(\d+b\))(?=;|$)`. Unfortunately, KQL does not support negative lookaheads.

Comment: Joseph, please add the required results in a tabular format.

Answer (score 1):

[mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) operator

```
datatable (item:string ) [
'file1.png (445b); file2.pdf (2345b); file3.jpg (343b); file4.docx (3243b);',
'file1.src (3243b); file2.ps2 (24b); file3.jpg (300b); file4.jpg (326b);'
]
| mv-apply f = extract_all(@'([^<>:"\/\\\|\?\*;]+)\.([a-zA-z0-9]+) \((\d+)b\);', item) on
  ( 
    where f[1] !in~ ("png", "jpg")
    | summarize make_list(pack_array(f))
  )
```

| item | list_ |
| --- | --- |
| file1.png (445b); file2.pdf (2345b); file3.jpg (343b); file4.docx (3243b); | [["file2","pdf","2345","b"],["file4","docx","3243","b"]] |
| file1.src (3243b); file2.ps2 (24b); file3.jpg (300b); file4.jpg (326b); | [["file1","src","3243","b"],["file2","ps2","24","b"]] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12Qb2uDMBCH3wt+h5tvvKzVWbWDtfv7OYyTqLHLGm2I2daK7LMvtrSFcXBwDz8e7q5mxlYpOaAwvF31RotuAwQy1/EbIfkiVHbGNF2WZA0TiUNVN4BxckVJ+KlsKEmTM0nDelftLYqPzJ9fdL2uLvjs62PrS//bouhqO5H4fnK5Tu46I7TfAVNKHqCBJ+B7o1llCiYlvvqYvT8+rzx6Rykd6Qu9XeczQkPMWDC8BUMUPNgZKCKtZ6Sk034wnU9g17kOAMLUAX4+uObQZIscbkT3C+jZZ3hz8Ow6HjllRui/2pZpMXBo2ZYXUvQGFau2BdOaHbAhxyT5A3FqogVrAQAA)

Answer (score 1):

[replace_regex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replace-regex-function)

```
datatable (item:string ) [
'file1.png (445b); file2.pdf (2345b); file3.jpg (343b); file4.docx (3243b);',
'file1.src (3243b); file2.ps2 (24b); file3.jpg (300b); file4.jpg (326b);'
]
| extend clean_item = replace_regex(item, @'([^<>:"\/\\\|\?\*;]+)\.(?i:png|jpg) \((\d+)b\);', "")
| extend extract_all(@'([^<>:"\/\\\|\?\*;]+)\.([a-zA-z0-9]+) \((\d+)b\);', clean_item)
```

| item | clean_item | Column1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| file1.png (445b); file2.pdf (2345b); file3.jpg (343b); file4.docx (3243b); | file2.pdf (2345b); file4.docx (3243b); | [[" file2","pdf","2345"],[" file4","docx","3243"]] |
| file1.src (3243b); file2.ps2 (24b); file3.jpg (300b); file4.jpg (326b); | file1.src (3243b); file2.ps2 (24b); | [["file1","src","3243"],[" file2","ps2","24"]] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WPUWuDMBDH3wW/w%20GLyVozF7PB7LZun8PrJCZpcWROYh6k%20OEXO1pHodzDcT%20O3/1PSx%20qsQZI6813OXjXdgegUMVRum%20teWB9mIkQjw3dwEw46/UeCC8WVLCvPiwVojgTwfSPGgPiJ5auL7rBqQs%20%20wYefOLalueL7Y/wp9kVR7s4msCM3nQalDWyq%20fw8ArO9FYqUztzMOPpozW8p6T6fHkrE7xHxAm3eLfZrSgysm3L8NwU3BSQENQr2uAcFpKE/jsRmpPK19JacttWyez4kR3z7DnMV74lJP0Fo3D4IXIBAAA=)

Answer (score 0):

And another option that doesn't rely on (arguably) hard to read regular expressions:

```
datatable (item:string ) [
'file1.png (445b); file2.pdf (2345b); file3.jpg (343b); file4.docx (3243b);',
'file1.src (3243b); file2.ps2 (24b); file3.jpg (300b); file4.jpg (326b);'
]
| extend s=split(item, "; ")
| mv-expand s
| parse s with fileName "." extension " (" fileSize "b)" rest
| where extension !in ("png", "jpg")
| extend image = bag_pack("fileName", fileName, "extension", extension, "fileSizeBytes", fileSize)
| summarize make_list(image) by item
```

| item | list_image |
| --- | --- |
| file1.png (445b); file2.pdf (2345b); file3.jpg (343b); file4.docx (3243b); | [ { "fileName": "file2", "extension": "pdf", "fileSizeBytes": "2345" }, { "fileName": "file4", "extension": "docx", "fileSizeBytes": "3243" } ] |
| file1.src (3243b); file2.ps2 (24b); file3.jpg (300b); file4.jpg (326b); | [ { "fileName": "file1", "extension": "src", "fileSizeBytes": "3243" }, { "fileName": "file2", "extension": "ps2", "fileSizeBytes": "24" } ] |

According to the original regular expression `;` isn't part of the filename which means simply splitting on `;` should be safe.